# Receiving data returned from a sever side on call firebase function on client-side (swift)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have included my server-side code (Javascript/Typescript) and the function that calls the httpsCallable function on the client-side (swift). The issue I am having is that the data is retrieved properly on the sever from the database, but the result.data returned to my client is always null. A side note my database has two different types of users that is why there are two different converters, doc reads, etc.

```
@IBAction func loginButtonIsPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        if let error = validateFields(){
            textHelpers.showError("Issue with login completion", error, self)
            return
        }
        let email = self.email.text!
        let password = self.password.text!
        
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { [weak self] authResult, error in
          guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
          // ...
            if let user = authResult?.user {
                let uid = user.uid
                let functions = Functions.functions()
                functions.httpsCallable("userLoggedIn").call(){ [self] (result,error) in
                    if let error = error as NSError? {
                        if error.domain == FunctionsErrorDomain {
                            let message = error.localizedDescription
                            textHelpers.showError("Error logging in", message, self!)
                        }
                    }
                    
                    if let text = try? FirebaseDecoder().decode(loginAdvUser.self, from: result?.data){
                        print(text)
                      }
                         
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
    }
        
  
    func validateFields() -> String? {
        if password.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == "" || email.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == "" {
            return "Please fill in all fields"
        }
        return nil
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        
    }
}

struct loginBlogUser: Codable {
    var Account_Type: String
    var First_Name: String
    var Last_Name: String
    var Phone_Number: String
    var Date_of_Birth: String
    var Region: String?
    var State: String?
    var City: String?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case Account_Type = "Account_Type"
        case First_Name = "First_Name"
        case Last_Name = "Last_Name"
        case Phone_Number = "Phone_Number"
        case Date_of_Birth = "Date_of_Birth"
        case Region = "Region"
        case State = "State"
        case City = "City"
    }
}

struct loginAdvUser: Codable {
    var Account_Type: String
    var First_Name: String
    var Last_Name: String
    var Phone_Number: String
    var Country: String?
    var Subscription_Type: String?
            
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case Account_Type = "Account_Type"
        case First_Name = "First_Name"
        case Last_Name = "Last_Name"
        case Phone_Number = "Phone_Number"
        case Country = "Country"
        case Subscription_Type = "Subscription_Type"
        }
    }
```

```
class AdvUser {
    Account_Type: any;
    First_Name: any;
    Last_Name: any;
    Phone_Number: any;
    Country: any;
    Subscription_Type: any;
    constructor(Account_Type: any, First_Name: any, Last_Name: any, Phone_Number: any, Country: any, Subscription_Type: any){
        this.Account_Type = Account_Type;
        this.First_Name = First_Name;
        this.Last_Name = Last_Name;
        this.Phone_Number = Phone_Number;
        this.Country = Country;
        this.Subscription_Type = Subscription_Type;
    }
    toString(){
        return this.Account_Type + ', ' + this.First_Name + ', ' + this.Last_Name + ', ' + this.Phone_Number + ', ' + this.Country + ', ' + this.Subscription_Type;
    }
}

class BlogUser {
    Account_Type: any;
    First_Name: any;
    Last_Name: any;
    Phone_Number: any;
    Date_Of_Birth: any;
    Region: any;
    State: any;
    City: any;
    constructor(Account_Type: any, First_Name: any, Last_Name: any, Phone_Number: any, Date_Of_Birth: any, Region: any, State: any, City: any){
        this.Account_Type = Account_Type;
        this.First_Name = First_Name;
        this.Last_Name = Last_Name;
        this.Phone_Number = Phone_Number;
        this.Date_Of_Birth = Date_Of_Birth;
        this.Region = Region;
        this.State = State;
        this.City = City;
    }
    toString(){
        return this.Account_Type + ', ' + this.First_Name + ', ' + this.Last_Name + ', ' + this.Phone_Number + ', ' + this.Date_Of_Birth + ', ' + this.Region + ', ' + this.State + ', ' + this.City;
    }
}

const blogConverter = {
    toFirestore: function(blogUser: { Account_Type: any; First_Name: any; Last_Name: any; Phone_Number: any; Date_Of_Birth: any; Region: any; State: any; City: any; }){
        return {
            Account_Type: blogUser.Account_Type,
            First_Name: blogUser.First_Name,
            Last_Name: blogUser.Last_Name,
            Phone_Number: blogUser.Phone_Number,
            Date_Of_Birth: blogUser.Date_Of_Birth,
            Region: blogUser.Region,
            State: blogUser.State,
            City: blogUser.City,
            }
    },
    fromFirestore: function(snapshot: admin.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot){
        const data = snapshot.data();
        return new BlogUser(data.Account_Type, data.First_Name, data.Last_Name, data.Phone_Number, data.Date_Of_Birth, data.Region, data.State, data.City);
    },
}

const advConverter = {
    toFirestore: function(advUser: { Account_Type: any; First_Name: any; Last_Name: any; Phone_Number: any; Country: any; Subscription_Type: any; }){
        return {
            Account_Type: advUser.Account_Type,
            First_Name: advUser.First_Name,
            Last_Name: advUser.Last_Name,
            Phone_Number: advUser.Phone_Number,
            Country: advUser.Country,
            Subscription_Type: advUser.Subscription_Type,
            }
    },
    fromFirestore: function(snapshot: admin.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot){
        const data = snapshot.data();
        return new AdvUser(data.Account_Type, data.First_Name, data.Last_Name, data.Phone_Number, data.Country, data.Subscription_Type);
    },
}

exports.userLoggedIn = functions.https.onCall((data,context) => {
    if(!context.auth){
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unauthenticated', 'user must sign in');
    }

    const userARef = admin.firestore().collection('users/advertiserUsers/userAccounts/').doc(context.auth.uid);
    const userBRef = admin.firestore().collection('users/bloggerUsers/userAccounts').doc(context.auth.uid);
    const testAResult = accountTester(userARef, advConverter);
    if(testAResult !== null){  
        console.log('here');
        return testAResult;
    }
    const testBResult = accountTester(userBRef, blogConverter);
    console.log('here2');
    return testBResult;    
    });

function accountTester(userRef:FirebaseFirestore.DocumentReference<FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData>, converter: FirebaseFirestore.FirestoreDataConverter<unknown>) {
    userRef.withConverter(converter).get().then(function(doc){
        if(doc.exists){
            const user = doc.data();
            return user;
        }else{
            console.log("No document exists!");
            return null;
        }
    }).catch(function(error){
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Don't make us take a guess as to at what line you get data returned as nil.

Comment: It would be in the only onCall function I included. The function is called "userLoggedIn" and begins with "exports."

Comment: What makes it a Swift question, then?

Answer (score 0):

Your Cloud Function isn't actually returning anything to the client.  If you want to see that for yourself, log the value of `testBResult` before you return it.

The bottom line is that you're not dealing with promises correctly.  When you have asynchronous work like Firestore queries to do, you are obliged to return a promise that resolves to the object you want to serialize and send to the client.  The code you have now isn't actually waiting for the queries to finish.  `then` doesn't wait for the query to finish.  It is just registering a callback to be invoked some time after the query finishes.

I suggest taking some time to learn how JS promises work.  Cloud Functions is a very good place to learn that, given the complexity of the environment.  I would also urge you to consider using the Firebase emulator suite to test your code locally so can experiment with it more easily without having to deploy your code each time.